# Generate multiple divs in an area

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to generate multiple divs in a specified area. I want to load the relative positions to the parent of these divs out of a database.

So for example:

1. div 1 - 250px, 100px
2. div 2 - 400px, 800px
3. div 3 - 50px, 85px

As you can see the problem here is that these divs aren't loaded in order of their relative location. Also there will be overlapping divs.

How would I go about placing these in the correct relative position to the parent.

I load these locations out of a MySQL database with PHP, they each have an id and the locations. I want to put all the divs in one parent div.

I tried using both relative and absolute position in CSS but they didn't get me the desired result.

Comment: Please provide more information. What does the surrounding code look like? What have tried and what was the result? What backend system will you be using (how will you connect to the database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parent have a position of relative or absolute. Then give all children position 'absolute' with a left and top which come from the database.

HTML:

```
<DIV id="parent">
    <DIV STYLE="left: 25px; top: 10px">DIV 1</DIV>
    <DIV STYLE="left: 40px; top: 80px">DIV 2</DIV>
    <DIV STYLE="left: 50px; top: 85px">DIV 3</DIV>
</DIV>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#parent DIV {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xgG2C/

Answer (score 0):

you can load these divs in any order and solve the problem of overlaping by attaching a `onmouseover` event, which will toggle the highest `z-index` for the DIV that has triggered that event, making that DIV overlap others, like so

```
echo '<div>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlResult)) {
    echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:'.$row['top'].'; left:'.$row['left'].';"></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Then, when your DIVs are ready, you can attach the onmouseover event to them. In jQuery it will look like this:

```
$('div div').mouseover(function() {
    $('div div').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('mouseover');
});
```

and a little CSS to make

```
div div {z-index:1}
div.mouseover {z-index:1000}
```